# Find a function whose Fourier transform is the following

Tags: fourier-analysis

Find a function whose Fourier transform is the following:

$$\frac{1}{(4+k^{2})(9+k^{2})}$$

I know that $f(x) = F^{-1}\{\hat{f}(k)\}$ so I get:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}dk$$

I'm unsure about how to solve this integral.. is there a trick that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you know complex analysis? You can do residue theorem.

Comment: You can use the Fourier transform table.

Comment: after using partial fractions

Comment: Or the convolution theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Use complex analysis.  Assuming $x$ is positive, we'll close the contour upstairs so that the exponential develops a negative real part and the contribution from the semicircle vanishes.  We have a pole at $2i$ and another at $3i$ in the upper half plane, and both are simple so the answer is quick and easy.  The answer I am getting is $$\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}-\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}\right).$$
If $x$ is negative, we close downstairs (remembering to account for a sign because the integral is now taken in a clockwise sense).  This gives the same, but with $x$ replaced with $-x$, so the inverse Fourier transform is given by the above with $x$ replaced with the absolute value of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use partial fractions
$$
           \frac{1}{(4+k^{2})(9+k^{2})}=\frac{1}{5}\left[\frac{1}{4+k^{2}}-\frac{1}{9+k^{2}}\right]
$$
I assume these are known to you.